# python client and perl server: packing and unpacking bytes to send/receive

Tags: python, perl, sockets

python_client.py

```
def send_one_message(sock, data):
    length = len(data)
    sock.sendall(struct.pack('!I', length))
    sock.sendall(data)
```

perl_server.pl

```
sub ntohl {
    unpack("I", pack("N", $_[0]));
}

my $line = "";
$client_socket->recv($line, 4);
my $line_length = ntohl($line);
print "expected to receive $line_length bytes\n";

$client_socket->recv($line, $line_length);
print "$line\n";
```

I get this error:
`Argument "\0\0\0C" isn't numeric in pack` in perl_server.pl

I dont think I am unpacking correctly in perl_server.pl

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Сухой27 no, just python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed ntohl

```
sub ntohl {
    unpack("I",  $_[0]);
}
```

and

```
sock.sendall(struct.pack('I', length))
```